# Compact sequence of continuous functions are bounded

Tags: real-analysis

> If $K\subset \mathbb{R}^p$ is compact and $(f_n)$ is a sequence of
>   continuous functions on $K$ to $\mathbb{R}^q$ which is uniformly
>   convergent on $K$, show that the family $\{f_n\}$ is bounded on $K$.

Isn't there a theorem that states this? But, I know I must prove that there exists $M>0$ such that $||f_n(x)||\le M$ for all $x\in K$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ which means I have to construct a sequence that converges? How will I be able to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\varepsilon=1$, there being $N$, if
$n\geqslant N$,  then 
\[|f_n(x)-f_N(x)|<1
\  \forall x\in K.
\]
so
\[|f_n(x)|<1+|f_N(x)|=M+1\   n\geqslant N,\]
here, $M$ is  maximun of $f_N$ on K, because $f_N$ is continuous and K is compact.
And, the $N-1$ functions ahead are all bounded. We can have common maximun value, when taking the largest one of them.
 so sequence $f_n$ can be bounded.

Comment: I cant read your answer, I think you forgot to use $$ to close your latex.

Comment: The answer seems to be OK.

Comment: $\epsilon=1$,there being N, if $n\geq N$, then 
\[|f_n(x)-f_N(x)|<1 \ \forall x\in K. \]
 so \[|f_n(x)|<1+|f_N(x)|=M+1\ n\geqslant N,\] 
 here,$M $is maximun of $f_N$ on K,because $f_N$ is continuous and K is compact. And ,the $N-1$ functions ahead are all bounded.we can have common maximun value,when taking the largest one of them. so sequence$ {f_n} $can be bounded.

Comment: my browser must be out of whack then because I cant read it.

Comment: use `\\[ ... \\]` or `$$ ... $$` for displayed math. @Q.matin: it should be readable now.

Comment: @user63788 Why did you choose $1$?

Comment: it doesn't matter with the selection of $\epsilon$. when we have choosen $\epsilon$ ,it is fixed. of course,you can choose other number, 1 is only common selection.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the limit of the sequence $\{f_n\}$ to bound it.

Comment: Can you provide a more stronger hint?

Comment: Hint 2:Let $f$ be the limit of the sequence. Then $||f_n-f||<1$ for almost all $n$.

Comment: What I got is:

Let $f_n$ be a sequence that uniformly converges, then pick any integer $N$ such that $m,n\ge \mathbb{N}$ then $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$. I dont know why you chose $1$? But since $f$ is convergent continuous function it has a supremum ...